# QGIS street labelling when rotating in composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, line

When labeling streets in a QGISmap everything's OK, no label are upside-down.
But I need to rotate at 180° in the composer. Labels of lines don't flip, so they are upside-down!

I tried to "show reversed labels" when a "rotation is done" (sorry my QGIS is in French, words may not be the right ones); and I tried "line orientation dependent position" but nothing happens.

Does someone know if it is possible to flip the lines or the label curved on the line?